# Meteor JS and TinyPNG API to compress uploaded PNG

Tags: node.js, file-upload, meteor

I'm trying to recompress a PNG after upload and crop using tinyPNG API https://tinypng.com/developers/reference

My HTTP request in the server method looks like :

```
var tinyResponse = HTTP.post('https://api.tinypng.com/shrink', {auth: 'api:<myAPIkey>', data: image});
```

Where image is the base64 data like : data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...

The api then tels me : "Does not appear to be a PNG file"

So I guess the TinyPNG API doesn't like the base64 format. What I should do is store the base64 into a temp file, use the API to compress, get the file back and re-encode it in base64. Yes what I want is to store the image file in the mongodb directly.

But my knowledge of node.js and Meteor is not suffisant for the moment.

Can someone throw me a bone here ? Thx

(Maybe I'm totally wrong and should use GM and cfs packages)

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you provided more code or even your github repo but check the documentation for node: https://tinypng.com/developers/reference#node-js

You can use NPM packages with Meteor: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Npm-depends